# Programmatically created RadioButtonList needs 2 clicks

Tags: asp.net

I have a page (using MS Ajax). depending on other options, I may need to create a radio Button List inside a Panel.
This is done as per below.

```
 RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();
    rbl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(answer_Click);
    rbl.AutoPostBack = true;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> d in _answers)
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem(d.Key.ToString(), d.Key.ToString());
        li.Attributes.Add("class", "radio");            
        rbl.Items.Add(li);
    }
    p.Controls.Add(rbl);
```

this works fine, unless after the postback I need another RadioButton List. The list is drawn correctly, with all the correct options, but now when I click on an option the first time, it fills in and then resets. It takes a second click to get it to set and trigger the SelectedIndexChanged Event.

Im destroying and recreating the rbl once answer_Click is triggered (I know this as the next question that is created has different answers and options).

So, any ideas as to why it is I need to click twice on the second List?

Comment: Ahy is it I always figure the answer out / find it after posting. Sorry, its something to do with the order I am binding the Event Handler and calling the Page.DataBind methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt!

Looks like you have a ViewState issue. Controls are created after the LoadViewState trigger, so they doesn't get their values from the browser to load. You must save this value somewhere, using JS, ViewState, QueryString, Session, DB to persiste the state, and then load the selected value into each one.

Hopes this help you! Take a look here for more info about [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).